# How to get a reason for a DateTime parsing failure?

Tags: c#, .net

When I use standard library date and time parsing methods (`DateTime.ParseExact`, `DateTime.TryParse` etc.) and the operation fails, all I got is the generic message:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Examples:

- has additional whitespace

  ```
  DateTime.ParseExact("12.04.2018  13:10", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
  ```
- has `AB` in place where hour is expected

  ```
  DateTime.ParseExact("12.04.2018 AB:10", "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind)
  ```

What I would like to have is the precise reason for the error. Something similar to the following would be great:

> Parsing of string "12.04.2018 AB:10" with format "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm"
>   failed because at index 11 ("AB:10") hour was expected (HH).

EDIT: some existing library would satisfy my needs, it does not need to be part of c# standard library.

Comment: Not available. Period

Comment: The best thing you can do is display an error message with the expected date format (i.e. if you want to display an error to an end user)

Comment: It's possible to create a parser that will provide this much detail, but a `DateTime` is sufficiently simple that no human reader should need more than "your string `xxx` did not match format `fff`". A message like that is easily produced on encountering the error.

Comment: You can copy the source and return the index in the `while`-loop of this method which starts with _"scan every character in format"_ if `ParseByFormat` returned `false`: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,2558c4cbd566081b But you'll probably have to copy thousands of lines.

Answer (score 3):

You would have to write your own parsing functions then. The .NET framework libraries do not provide a greater level of detail in its exception texts here. There is also no such thing as a "verbosity flag". [Internally](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/datetimeparse.cs,4158) the framework tracks four different `ParseFailureKind` values:

- ArgumentNull
- Format
- FormatWithParameter
- FormatBadDatetimeCalendar

So at most you get an indication of the invalid argument (like "Format_BadDayOfWeek"), but no character position.

To address your first example, you can enable whitespace tolerance with ParseExact, like this:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(
    "12.04.2018  13:10", 
    "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, 
    DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind | DateTimeStyles.AllowWhiteSpaces
);
```